# Show Json in SectionList - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I need to show the api return in an sectionlist.

My Return API is:

```
console.log(apidata)
Return is:
Array [
      Object {
        "descfolder": "Folder Test",
        "enable": 1,
        "folderid": 1,
        "id": 6,
        "url": "http://www.yahoo.com.",
        "userid": 2,
        "usernamepassword": "cx8",
      },
      Object {
        "descfolder": "Folder Test",
        "enable": 1,
        "folderid": 1,
        "id": 7,
        "url": "Www.amazon.com",
        "userid": 2,
        "usernamepassword": "cx7",
      },
      Object {
        "descfolder": "FolderXXX",
        "enable": 1,
        "folderid": 2,
        "id": 5,
        "url": "http://www.xxxx.com",
        "userid": 2,
        "usernamepassword": "cy558",
      },
      Object {
        "descfolder": "FolderXXX",
        "enable": 1,
        "folderid": 2,
        "id": 8,
        "url": "Http Secreto",
        "userid": 2,
        "usernamepassword": "cxfd222",
      },
      Object {
        "descfolder": "Folder5",
        "enable": 1,
        "folderid": 3,
        "id": 4,
        "url": "URL997",
        "userid": 2,
        "usernamepassword": "cxd654",
      },
    ]
```

Like the SectionList example: https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

I want show the sectionList like the example below

```
 
   Folder2 
        CX7
        CX8
    FolderXXX
        cy558
        cxfd222
    Folder5
        cxd654
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use `SectionList` with the `{title: '', data: []}` format. So after receiving response, you have to format your `JSON` something like this.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    "title": "Folder2",
    "data": [
      "CX7",
      "CX8"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "FolderXXX",
    "data": [
      "cy558",
      "cxfd222"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Folder5",
    "data": [
      "cxd654"
    ]
  }
]
```

You can supply the object also in the `data` key. Like this

```
{
    "title": "Folder5",
    "data": [
       {
          "descfolder": "Folder5",
          "enable": 1,
          "folderid": 3,
          "id": 4,
          "url": "URL997",
          "userid": 2,
          "usernamepassword": "cxd654",
       }
    ]
  }
```

and then you can access it in `renderItem`.

Comment: Hi @arthankamal,
Tks! but I need to understand how I can format my API return (Json) like the Section List needs.